# C++ variable number generic parameters in map

Tags: c++

I have some simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

class Calculator{
    private:
        map<string, double (Calculator::*)(double)> mp = {
            {"ABS", &Calculator::abs}};

    public:

    Calculator(){
        cout << (this->*mp["ABS"])(-4.2655) << "\n";
    }

    double abs(double ting){
        return fabs(ting);
    }

};

int main() {
    Calculator calc;
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles OK with no errors. However, as seen in the example above, the functions contained in the `map` only allow one parameter of `double` type. However, I would like to allow for a variable number of parameters with multiple types.

For example, as of now I have an `abs()` method, but if I were to add a `sigma()` function to my `map`, which takes parameters `int startVal, int endVal, string expression`, how could I go about doing this with the layout shown?

I understand a `template<>` may be of use here, but I am fairly new to this, and would like to know how (or if) it should be used here.

Comment: make the method take a vector of variants

Comment: This cannot be done in C++ as described, C++ simply doesn't work this way, on a fundamental level.

Comment: I see, but there must be some technique to allow for generic parameters (and a variable number of them); if not, is there an alternative you could suggest to achieve something similar or just a place I can look to gain some intution on an alternative

Comment: No, there isn't. It is fundamental to C++ that the types of every object is specified, and known, at compile time. There is no such thing as "generic parameters" in C++.  One might think that `std::any` proves this assertion wrong, but it doesn't once it is fully understood how `std::any` really works. You might as well put `std::any` in your map, attempt to use it, as desired, and see how well that works...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik `std::any` is ultimately a *"technique to allow for generic parameters"*.

Comment: I obviously have very little experience surrounding this field, but does the `template<>` feature allow for anything resembling such an idea or is this the incorrect use?

Comment: What should happen if you write `(this->*mp["sigma"])(-4.2655)`?

Comment: `sigma()` will return an exception in this case as it has not got enough parameters, `sigma()` as stated should take `int startVal, int endVal, string expression`

Comment: You could write a wrapper class that holds on to the function/functor and in the wrapper class provide a `operator()` that forwards on the the wrapped function like `template <typename... Args> auto operator()(Args&&... args) { return wrapped_function(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }`

Comment: @CGI-Demon402 it doesn't work like that in C++ (or C) - functions don't check the number of parameters at runtime. Every time you call a function, the compiler has to know the parameters are correct.

Comment: `tempalte<>` is a specialization. It has nothing to do, whatsoever, with any "generic parameters".

Comment: Java allows a variable number of parameters of the same type (as opposed to overloading, which is a fixed number of parameters of possibly different types) by passing them in as an array behind the scenes. You can use a vector in C++. If you need them to be different types, Maybe use a struct (with `has_X` indicators), but you'll have to decode what gets passed in to determine how to handle it, so why not declare the method you want with the parameters you want?

Answer (score 2):

how about this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

#include <any>
using namespace std;
using func= std::function<double(std::vector<any>)>;

class Calculator {
private:
    map<string,func> funcs= {
        {"ABS", &Calculator::abs},
    {"ADD", &Calculator::add} };

public:

    Calculator() {
        any life = -42.0;
        std::vector<any> args;
        args.push_back(life);
        cout << funcs["ABS"](args) << "\n";

        any other = 99.4;
        args.push_back(other);

        cout << funcs["ADD"](args);

    }
   
    static double abs(vector<any> args) {
        return fabs(any_cast<double>(args[0]));
    }
    static double add(vector<any> args) {
        return any_cast<double>(args[0]) + any_cast<double>(args[1]);
    }
};

int main() {
    Calculator calc;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: using `std::vector::at` would make it a bit safer (currently passing the wrong number of arguments would be UB) - i.e. `any_cast<double>(args.at(0)) + any_cast<double>(args.at(1))` (`operator[]` does no bounds checking, but `.at()` does)

Comment: @Turtlefight - yup , and make sure we find a func entry in the map, and that the args are the correct type.

Comment: @pm100 ah right also gotta use `.at()` for the map accesses (the "feature" that `std::map::operator[]` does an insert for non-existing elements still gets me every time :D). The args should be no problem, the overload of `any_cast` you're using should throw an exception in case the cast fails.